# how to make statements in javascript function run sequentially in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am making a chrome extension and in my extension I am sending message from content script to background script.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function triggerNew(request) {
    if (request.method == "addNew") {
      //alert("in content script");
      var x=startClick();
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({name: "Response" , data : x});
    }
  }
);

`function startClick(){
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
var target = e.target || event.srcElement;
return target;
}`
```

I have called a function `startClick` in my content script, but Response message is getting sent before `startClick` executes.

How to make it send the data I get in variable `x` from `startClick` function?

Comment: Almost certainly a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) but the question is missing the `startClick` function.

Comment: i went through that link but could not understand much. may you tell me how to achieve it here ? @Quentin

Comment: Statements do not get reordered. statClick gets called before sendMessage. I suspect you do somethin asynchronous inside startClick, show us some more code.

Comment: @Ram — No, because, as I said, your question is missing most of the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `startClick` is called after `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, the problem is in your usage of the callback method.

You callback method's signature must look like this:

```
function(any message, MessageSender sender, function sendResponse) {...};
```

To send a response to a call to `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`, you must use the `sendResponse` function as indicated here in the doc: 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage

Important note: As indicated in the doc (make sure you read it all), your callback function must return `true` in order to keep the sendResponse function valid. This is essential if you want to call `sendResponse` from an asynchronous function.

Edit: try this

background:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function triggerNew(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.method == "addNew") {
            var x = startClick();
            sendResponse({
                data: x
            });
        }
    }
);
```

content script:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({method: 'addNew'} , function(response) {
    alert(response.data);
});
```